# What is the difference between Moore's algorithm and partition refinement algorithm for DFA minimization?

Tags: finite-automata, compilers, pushdown-automata

Both the algorithms use the partition method to minimize the DFA. I cannot understand the difference between them. Can someone give an example where we can see the difference between them.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried working through an example or two by hand to see what happens?  When you say partition refinement, do you mean [Hopcroft's algoirthm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization#Hopcroft.27s_algorithm)?  I'm not sure how to answer a question of the form "What is the difference...?" -- they are different algorithms with many differences; what specifically are you looking for, and how will you use or evaluate any answers you get?  I encourage you to edit the question to show what you've tried and what specifically you're asking.

Comment: The difference between Moore and Hopcroft should be pretty close to the difference between Kanellakis&Smolka versus Paige-Tarjan for computing bisimulation (since DFA minimization is just a special case of finding the quotient for maximal bisimulation).  Moore simply refines naively while Hopcroft avoids unneed work (this is done by adding only one of the two subblocks when doing the splitting).